# How to update MenuItem Control Template in c# wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am new to c# wpf application and I am trying to update default MenuItem control template using style in c# wpf application. I am trying to update material design icon Kind to User using Tag in xaml.

```
<MenuItem Header="Test Menu Item" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemCustomStyle}" Tag="User"/>
```

In the styles I am using template binding to update Kind of PackIcon.

```
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon x:Name="menuItemIcon" Height="25" Kind="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Margin="10,5,5,10" Width="25"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="menuItemTitle" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16" Margin="0,7" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="menuItemIcon" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="stackpanel" Value="DarkGray"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="menuItemTitle" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

How do I achieve it in c# wpf application. Am I missing something. Should I be using Dependency property to achieve it. If yes, How?

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"` sets the source of the binding to the parent, which is the MenuItem in this case. This allows you to access properties of the MenuItem within the control template.

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon x:Name="menuItemIcon" Height="25" Margin="10,5,5,10" Width="25">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon.Kind>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Tag"/>
        </materialDesign:PackIcon.Kind>
 </materialDesign:PackIcon>
```

Full sample:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon x:Name="menuItemIcon" Height="25" Margin="10,5,5,10" Width="25">
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon.Kind>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Tag"/>
                                </materialDesign:PackIcon.Kind>
                            </materialDesign:PackIcon>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="menuItemTitle" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16" Margin="0,7" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="menuItemIcon" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="stackpanel" Value="DarkGray"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="menuItemTitle" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <MenuItem Header="Test Menu Item" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemCustomStyle}" Tag="User"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, can you explain how does it work

Comment: The code binds the Kind property of the template to the templates caller at the Tag property.

Comment: This is just a single Tag, what if I want to add few more properties such as IconColor and so on, is there a better way to do it using DependencyProperty for MenuItem

Comment: That was not part the question i suggest asking a new question. For The color i suggest something like this: but i did not test it `IconColor="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Foreground}"/>`